# Environment variables are not available on Azure app service (docker)

Tags: docker, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I'm using [Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/products/app-service/web/) for a Drupal application.
I build my own docker image with a Dockerfile and when it start, i'm not able to see any environment variables.

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM --platform=amd64 php:8.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
  curl \
  git \
  zip \
  unzip \
  libzip-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  openssh-server \
  cifs-utils \
  lsb-release \
  gpg \
  mariadb-client \
  nano

# add root to www-data group
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# SSH config for Azure
RUN rm /etc/ssh/sshd_config
COPY conf_sshd-azure.conf /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd 

# install php extensions
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
  install-php-extensions \
  opcache \
  zip \
  redis \
  pdo_mysql \
  gd \
  mysqli \
  uploadprogress

# enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod \
  rewrite \
  cache \
  expires \
  headers \
  cache_disk

COPY conf_php-opcache-prod.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/opcache.ini
COPY conf_php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/php.ini

COPY conf_apache-prd.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# copy source to the images
COPY ./html /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

# provide some nice shortcut
RUN ln -s /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush /usr/sbin/drush
RUN alias logs_error="tail -f /var/log/apache_error.log"
RUN alias logs_acces="tail -f /var/log/apache_access.log"

# make some fix on the drupal
RUN chmod 644 /var/www/html/web/sites/default/settings*
#RUN composer clearcache

# move to project folder on ssh login
RUN echo 'cd /var/www/html' >>/root/.bash_profile
WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 2222 80

# this is a test
ENV DB_database         ='blabal'
ENV DB_username         ='blabal'
ENV DB_password         ='blabal'
ENV DB_host             ='blabal'
ENV SETTINGS_hash_salt  ='blabal'

# start ssh and apache service
COPY entrypoint_apachephp.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Then, I build image and upload it to an Azure Container Registry and using it on a app service using deployment center :

[image: deployment center]

On the log, I can see

```
2023-08-09T19:36:23.773Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2023-08-09T19:36:23.826Z INFO - Starting container for site
2023-08-09T19:36:23.827Z INFO - docker run -d --expose=80 --name project-dev_7_1fdb9d01 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=project-dev -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=project-dev.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxx -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False project.azurecr.io/fondation:1.1 --env DB_database=kiwi2
...
2023-08-09T19:36:30.871Z INFO - Container project-dev_7_1fdb9d01 for site project-dev initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

but with `printenv`, I can't see any of the environment variables. I should be able to see `WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED` and other environment variables set on startup.

note :

- I know that startup file or command is wrong, it's a unsuccessful test.
- I tried to disable 'enable persistent storage" as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73634150/azure-app-service-environment-variables-are-not-available-in-container/73661810#73661810) without success
  [image]
- none of the application settings variable is available on the container
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `eval $(printenv | sed -n "s/^\([^=]\+\)=\(.*\)$/export \1=\2/p" | sed 's/"/\\\"/g' | sed '/=/s//="/' | sed 's/$/"/' >> /etc/profile)` in your [startup script file](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/04/27/2022-Enabling-SSH-on-Linux-Web-App-for-Containers/index.html) to show them in your SSH session.

[image]

I will also note that `WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED` or `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` does not have anything to do with [configuring environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#configure-environment-variables).